# Less Mixins: Border smart mixins

Tags: css, less, less-mixins

I've created separate mixins for border Shorthand property and another one for different sides.

**Shorthand**

```
.border(@width: 1px, @style: solid, @color: black){
      border: @arguments;
}
```

**Usage**

```
.class1{
     .border;
}
```

**For different sides**

```
.bordered(@property; @value) {
  border-@{property}: @value;
}
```

**Usage**

```
.class2{
     .bordered(top, 1px, solid red);
}
```

Is there a way to connect those too possibilities in one mixin?

Comment: something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029771/smart-margin-mixin-for-less/26449038

Comment: Note the [Pattern Matching](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature-pattern-matching) feature. I.e. instead of trying to merge different behaviors in the same mixin it's better to provide different mixins with the same name so that either behavior can be selected depending on number and value of arguments passed (and whatever other argument properties if you additionally use [Guards](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixin-guards-feature)).

Comment: (On the other hand speaking of this specific use-case it's not clear why you need such mixin at all - can't you just write normal `border: 1px solid black;` and `border-top: 1px solid red;` instead. And predicting the vendor-prefixing thing, just a one word hint: "Autoprefixer").

Answer (score 1):

To do this you can use LESS mixin guards which are something like if else conditions. More documentation about them is here - http://lesscss.org/features/#mixin-guards-feature
Here is a quick pseudocode of my idea:

```
.border when (@side = all) {
    .border(@width: 1px, @style: solid, @color: black, @side: all){
        border: @width @style @color;
    }
}
.border when not (@side = all) {
    .border(@property; @value; @side) {
        border-@{side}-@{property}: @value;
    }
}
```